# python modify Tkinter.Listbox parameter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, selection

I need help with Tkinter.Listbox class, I'm trying to change the color of selected line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(master, selectbackground="red")
```

If there are any other colours you want to change, then look them up at the [documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Listbox-class.html).

Comment: very much thanks, but, the position is always on bottom, when make side=top, left or right, always on bottom, if move up in write code position, same problem. but the background perfect.